# After updating to Android 2.3, the radio keeps running in the background

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I have an LG Optimus One and today I updated the firmware to the latest version.
I didn't know that with the firmware LG would also update Android.
Anyway, I finished the update and went at Phone Information menu.
There I saw that the Android version changed from 2.2 to 2.3.3
First I was happy to see that. I've been waiting a long time for this update.
But then I started to notice some strange things.
For example the Radio is always running in the background.
I tried with many different ways to close it, but nothing worked.
I used Adsvanced Task Killer and other apps and also tried to Force shut down.
But as I said, it keeps running. 
Anybody has the same problem? Is there any solution?

Also, although it says I have Android 2.3 the graphics are not the same.
The main screen is not like this:
http://developer.android.com/sdk/images/2.3/home-plain.png
(Only the browser icon changed)

Answer (score 1):

Firmware is a bit of a loose term.  With Android you can assume that all firmware updates are Android updates, even if it's only a minor version update.  It's rare that a new bootloader or something would be pushed out with no changes to the OS.

Anyways, Android has lots of services running in the background all the time.  Unless it's consuming your battery — it's probably idle and not using any — it's not a problem.  Running task killers is a great way to make your battery life worse and destabilize your phone, so definitely don't do that.

Finally, Android is customized to varying extent by the manufacturers.  Most of them at least change the launcher, which can make the homescreen look different.  The fact that it looks different from the stock Android homescreen isn't surprising :)